# Using Rails, or JavaScript, how do you connect webpages with active status?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

So I have two webpages that are being connected. On page one, the Landing Page, there is a dropdown menu with two options: Print or Mug. Both of these are anchor tags. The idea is that the user clicks on the dropdown and chooses Print or Mug of that image and is then redirected to the order page.

The Order Page has two sections: Print or Mug, list of images. The Print/Mug option are utilizing buttons and the images have a container around each of them for being marked as selected.

What I'm trying to do is whenever the user clicks on Print on the Landing Page the Order Page is loaded with Print being marked active and that associated image. Right now I can't get any of that to work. For the Landing Page I have:

```
    <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn merch dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    MERCH
    <span class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:16px;"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="/order" aria-pressed="false">Print</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/order" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">Mug</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For the Order Page I have:

```
    <% if params[:active] == 'Print'%>
  <button type="button" class="btn wk-prd-btn wk-click button-toggle active" style="margin-right: 15px; border-radius: 1px;" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
    PRINT</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn wk-prd-btn wk-click button-toggle" style="border-radius: 1px;">
    MUG</button>

  <% elsif params[:active] == 'Mug'%>
    <button type="button" class="btn wk-prd-btn wk-click button-toggle" style="margin-right: 15px; border-radius: 1px;" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
      PRINT</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn wk-prd-btn wk-click button-toggle active" style="border-radius: 1px;">
      MUG</button>

  <% else %>
    <button type="button" class="btn wk-prd-btn wk-click button-toggle" style="margin-right: 15px; border-radius: 1px;" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
      PRINT</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn wk-prd-btn wk-click button-toggle active" style="border-radius: 1px;">
      MUG</button>

  <% end %>
```

I really need to keep the Landing Page as is with the dropdown menu. What am I missing on the connection?

EDIT: Looks like I should probably using JS to do an eventlistener. Any advice for a JS noob?

Comment: What do your URLs looks like for each "mode"? `Print` and `Mug`. If they are different in any way, you can use regex in a JS event listener to check which one is active.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're generating your HTML from an `html.erb` file. In which case, your `link_to` should look something like (I'm guessing about your `path` name):

```
<%= link_to 'Print', new_order_path(active: 'Print'), ... %>
```

That will add a `active='Print'` query string to your URL which will then be passed onto your `OrdersController`.

Comment: Unfortunately the path needs to be an anchor tag as our CMS generates the routes. I did try using the following <%= link_to 'Print', "/order" %> and that works but I'm trying, unsuccessfully to hit the active.